# Microsoft LUIS: Pattern Features and Phrase List Features no longer detecting words

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have set up specific words both with pattern features (regex) and as exchangeable phrase list features. When I tested my model in early February, it was able to detect these words, with over 90% confidence, as entities.

The words I had set up with Pattern Features (regex) are "\bavailable\b", "\bpending\b" and "\bsold\b". I also have pending, available, sold and off market as a group in the Phrase List Features.

Now, NONE of these words are being picked up in my published application as entities. When I look at suggested utterances, again this entity is not being detected by LUIS.

For example, the following utterance (name changed for privacy):

"yes , available , i am putting it back on the market . Jim Smith , remax river city"

The word available is not detected as an entity.

This is a new issue - any ideas as to why this is happening now? Work around?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you have set any of this up?  Examples of inputs/outputs/regexes being used is a good place to start.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Best thing is to contact LUIS team and provide the app ID to investigate the issue